# Migrating an EJB local client from JBoss 6 to Wildfly 10

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I am facing the following JNDI lookup problem when getting a reference to a session bean in a legacy application during the **migration from JBoss 6 to WildFly 10**.

The following code, which works in JBoss 6, gets a reference to the session bean "OMGenEJB", which is then used to obtain a proxy object "genhome" to interact with the bean.

```
    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        Object objRef = ic.lookup("ejb/OMGenEJB");
        OMGenEJBHome genhome = 
          (OMGenEJBHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow ( objRef, OMGenEJBHome.class );
```

...

The **EJB home** interface is **OMGenEJBHome**.

The EJB implementation class is OMGenBean.

The bean is defined in the "ejb-jar.xml", as follows:

```
  <session >
     <ejb-name>OMGenEJB</ejb-name>
     <home>com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome</home>
     <remote>com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJB</remote>
     <service-endpoint>com.irisel.oms.ws.OMBrowserEndpoint</service-endpoint>
     <ejb-class>com.irisel.oms.ejb.browser.OMGenBean</ejb-class>
     <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
     <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
  </session>
```

Now the client class belongs to a WAR that is in the same EAR as the EJB jar.

The EAR is deployed correctly, and the server at startup logs the following **JNDI entries**:

```
21:39:18,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'OMGenEJB' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "HolmesEJB-2.0.jar" of deployment "HolmesBSS-2.0.ear"' are as follows:

java:global/HolmesBSS-2.0/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJB
java:app/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJB
java:module/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJB
java:jboss/exported/HolmesBSS-2.0/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJB
java:global/HolmesBSS-2.0/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.browser.OMGenBean
java:app/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.browser.OMGenBean
java:module/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.browser.OMGenBean
java:global/HolmesBSS-2.0/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome
java:app/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome
java:module/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome
java:jboss/exported/HolmesBSS-2.0/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome
```

Below is a modification to print JNDI entries, as seen in the client, both in the initial context, and "java:comp/env"

```
protected void init2(Credentials creds) throws SQLException, ConfigException, RemoteException {

    logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    try {

        logger.info("Connecting to ejb/OMGenEJB");

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

        // this code lists the entries in the initial context
        NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = ic.list("");
        while (list.hasMore()) {
          System.out.println(list.next().getName());
        }


        Context envCtx = (Context)ic.lookup("java:comp/env");

        // this code lists the entries in java:comp/env context
        list = envCtx.list("");
        while (list.hasMore()) {
              System.out.println(list.next().getName());
        }

        Object objRef2 = envCtx.lookup("ejb/OMGenEJB");

        logger.info("Narrowing to class OMGenEJBHome #"+OMGenEJBHome.class.hashCode());
        OMGenEJBHome genhome = (OMGenEJBHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(objRef2, OMGenEJBHome.class);
```

...

The modified code produces these logs:

```
23:23:43,445 INFO  [com.irisel.oms.olapi.CLEJBBrowser] (default task-16) Connecting to ejb/OMGenEJB
23:23:44,274 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Mail

23:23:44,669 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) TransactionManager
```

It turns out that **the initial context is "java:"** because Mail and TransactionManager have JNDI names "java:/Mail" and "java:/TransactionManager" respectively. However, I'd expect the relative path to be relative to java:comp/env.

Next to that, we see the entry "ejb":

```
23:23:46,163 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) com.irisel.oms.ws.server.KnockKnockImpl

23:23:46,789 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) ejb

23:23:50,146 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) com.irisel.oms.ws.server.HolmesImpl
```

My question is

1. why "java:comp/env" is no longer the default context but "java:",
2. why the lookup of "ejb/OMGenEJB" fails also in the modify code

   23:23:51,680 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Exception :WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/OMGenEJB

If we try to lookup "ejb" instead, the lookup works fine.

So I tried this as well:

```
    try {
        logger.info("Connecting to ejb/OMGenEJB");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = ic.list("");
        while (list.hasMore()) {
          System.out.println("ic entry:"+list.next().getName());
        }
        Context envCtx = (Context)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb");
        list = envCtx.list("");
        while (list.hasMore()) {
              System.out.println("envCtx entry:"+list.next().getName());
        }
        Object objRef2 = envCtx.lookup("OMGenEJB");
        logger.info("Narrowing to class OMGenEJBHome #"+OMGenEJBHome.class.hashCode());
        OMGenEJBHome genhome = (OMGenEJBHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(objRef2, OMGenEJBHome.class);

        //browser = genhome.create();
        //className = browser.getClassNames();

        genejb = genhome.create();
        appvo = (AppVO) AppVO.readObject64(this.genejb.exec("getApp",null,null));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception :"+ ex.getMessage());
        ConfigException ce = new ConfigException("Cannot initialize remote EJB client");
        ce.initCause(ex);
        throw ce;
    }
```

Which produces these logs:

```
00:35:52,048 INFO  [com.irisel.oms.olapi.CLEJBBrowser] (default task-2) Connecting to ejb/OMGenEJB
00:35:52,823 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) ic entry:Mail

00:35:53,123 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) ic entry:TransactionManager

00:35:53,992 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) envCtx entry:OMBrowserEJB

00:35:54,314 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) envCtx entry:OMGenEJB

00:36:25,649 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Exception :WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/OMGenEJB

00:36:25,650 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) com.irisel.util.ConfigException: Cannot initialize remote EJB client

00:36:25,650 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.irisel.oms.olapi.CLEJBBrowser.init2(CLEJBBrowser.java:82)
...
00:36:25,671 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0062: Failed to lookup env/ejb/OMGenEJB [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb/OMGenEJB -- service jboss.naming.context.java.ejb.OMGenEJB]

00:36:25,671 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:157)

... ... 39 more

00:36:25,672 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb/OMGenEJB -- service jboss.naming.context.java.ejb.OMGenEJB

00:36:25,672 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbLookupInjectionSource$1.getReference(EjbLookupInjectionSource.java:99)

00:36:25,672 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:143)

00:36:25,676 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 44 more

00:36:25,676 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb/OMGenEJB -- service jboss.naming.context.java.ejb.OMGenEJB

00:36:25,676 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbLookupInjectionSource$1.getReference(EjbLookupInjectionSource.java:81)

00:36:25,677 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 45 more
```

The solution that **works** is using the global or app names, the problem is it contains the ear name and version...

```
"java:global/HolmesBSS-2.0/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome"
"java:app/HolmesEJB-2.0/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome"
```

These **don't work**

```
"java:module/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.browser.OMGenBean"
"java:module/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome"
"java:comp/env/ejb/OMGenEJB"
```

I would like to check with you if you think this is compliant with the Java-7 specification.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The portable JNDI name for Java EE 7 has the form:

```
java:global/<app-name>/<module-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-bean-interface-name>
```

The default application name is the name of the ear without the extension (.ear). You can set the application name in the application.xml

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
    <application-name>myApp</application-name>
</application>
```

The default module name is the ejb-jar name without extension (.jar). You can change it in the ejb-jar.xml

```
<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version = "3.1"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <module-name>myModule</module-name>
</ejb-jar>
```

So the result is:

```
java:global/myApp/myModule/OMGenEJB!com.irisel.oms.ejb.interfaces.OMGenEJBHome
```

**Note**: you can't use "mappedName" in ejb-jar.xml to bind to different JNDI name, since Wildfly doesn't allow it. Wildfly only allow the aforementioned form.